How to display music and video in notification by MediaPlayer in Android webview?
I am an Android developer
I made a webview application for a music website
My problem is that when playing music in webview it should be displayed by default MediaPlayer of phone or Thisphone like Google Chrome, thanks.
my java code:

package com.prymie;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.webkit.WebView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public WebView p_ww_main;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle p_be_main){

super.onCreate(p_be_main);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



p_ww_main=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.p_ww_main);

p_ww_main.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

p_ww_main.loadUrl("https://music.com");



}

}

My goal is to have it displayed by Android MediaPlyer or Thisphone without access to non-nification
